# How can I switch out synthesized readers on a web page?

Tags: html, css, asp.net, text-to-speech, accessible

I am working on a version of "Huck Finn" that displays dialog in different colors, depending on the speaker (purple for Huckleberry, brown for his Pap, etc.) A working model can be seen [here](http://jsfiddle.net/clayshannon/tL4s1hjr/80/) by using CSS like so:

```
#huck {
    color: purple;
}
```

...and HTML like this:

```
<p><span id="huck">"But some says he got out and got away, and come to America."</span></p>
```

Is it possible to take it to the next level and have the voice reading the text (if the user is using that feature in their browser) switch off based on the id? A mean, gravelly voice for Pap, a young whippersnapper's voice for Huck, etc.?

If so, how? Has this been done? Can it be done, using the tools available to me in an ASP.NET site (C#, CSS, HTML, jQuery)?